# Binding entity framework winfoms

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework as a Model and WinForms as a View.

I have one combobox with Car Company and listBox with car models.

I created two BindingSources: `CompanyBindingSource` and `ModelBindingSource`.

- For `CompanyBindingSource` I set my Company entity as a DataSource
- `ModelBindingSource` Model entity as DataSource (all in the designer).

Then when I run application I set datasources for my BindingSources corresponding to my logic.

And it works great I have as datasource all models and companies but I would also like to have functionality that when I change Company in combobox, DataSource for listBox should contain only models from that company.

Is it possible to make it automatically ?

thanks for any help,
bye

Answer (score 1):

You might potentially be better off arranging your data into a single BindingSource, using hierarchical data so your Company contains a list of Models applicable to it.

This way, you'd bind your first combo to the datasource, and the second combo would cascade the Models property of the chosen Company.

Alternatively, catch the SelectedIndexChanged event and set a Filter for the ModelBindingSource entities.

Comment: I DOnt really know how to do this because when I in designer Use Datasource for my ListBox as Company->Models. Then set display memebr and value memebr nothing happens when I change data combobox selection. Should I do this from code ?

Comment: Ahh yes, I forgot about the designer aspect. I think you can specify a DataSource actually on the form like MyModelData, then cboCompany.DataSource would equal MyModelData.Companies. The MyModelData source would keep this in sync, so you can bind cboModels to MyModelData.Companies.Models.